# Unable to compile arduino sketch vscode for atmega 2560

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio

```
Compiling .pio/build/megaatmega2560/src/cstring/cstring.c.o
src/cstring/cstring.c:54:39: fatal error: cstring/internal/safestr.h: No such file or directory
 # include <cstring/internal/safestr.h>
                                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Try `#include "cstring/internal/safestr.h"` instead.

Comment: don't get it, this is exactly why it complains, it's in the std atmega src, I did not manually include it or anything

Comment: Others might be able to help if you show your compilation invocation